# Installing sympy on Mac does nothing

Tags: python, installation, sympy

When I try to install sympy through the terminal, see that it's installing, but when I import sympy in Jupiter notebook, it says that there is no module named sympy. I tried installing through Jupiter itself, but still nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using jupyter with a virtual environment? If you run `import sys; print(sys.path)` in your notebook, what does that output?

Comment: @C.Nivs I updated my question by adding a screenshot.

Comment: Did you notice that the "pip" error mentions Python 3.8, but your Jupyter session is Python 3.9?  That's the issue.  You have multiple Pythons installed.  Did you install one through homebrew?

Comment: @TimRoberts oh you are right! I haven't noticed.. I think I did install 3.8 my installing it from the python website and after that did some changes with my alias? but I am not sure.. how can I change that?

Comment: I'd recommend a [virtual environment manager](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```sh
python3.9 -m pip install sympy
```